# How do I prevent Neo4j DeadlockDetectedException?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm running Neo4j 2.3.3 Enterprise and using everyman/neo4jphp to access the database. I'm using Cypher parser version 1.9. As soon as my site gets a moderate amount of traffic, console.log displays the following error repeatedly:

```
WARN  /db/data/relationship/63568073 ForsetiClient[7] can't acquire     ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[1]} on NODE(73039), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[7].
 Wait list:ExclusiveLock[
Client[1] waits for [7]]
org.neo4j.kernel.DeadlockDetectedException: ForsetiClient[7] can't acquire ExclusiveLock{owner=ForsetiClient[1]} on NODE(73039), because holders of that lock are waiting for ForsetiClient[7].
 Wait list:ExclusiveLock[
Client[1] waits for [7]]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.lock.forseti.ForsetiClient.markAsWaitingFor(ForsetiClient.java:782)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.enterprise.lock.forseti.ForsetiClient.acquireExclusive(ForsetiClient.java:276)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations$1.visit(LockingStatementOperations.java:304)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.DiskLayer.relationshipVisit(DiskLayer.java:568)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.store.CacheLayer.relationshipVisit(CacheLayer.java:421)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.StateHandlingStatementOperations.relationshipVisit(StateHandlingStatementOperations.java:1329)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.relationshipVisit(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:388)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.relationshipDelete(LockingStatementOperations.java:297)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.relationshipDelete(OperationsFacade.java:873)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.RelationshipProxy.delete(RelationshipProxy.java:163)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.DatabaseActions.deleteRelationship(DatabaseActions.java:570)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.web.RestfulGraphDatabase.deleteRelationship(RestfulGraphDatabase.java:637)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
```

How can I prevent this? What could I be doing wrong?

**Update:**
I have upgraded my Cypher queries to 2.3 but I'm still encountering the problem.

Comment: Why are you using Cypher 1.9, and not Cypher 2.3?

Comment: Because the majority of queries were written a long time ago, and I hadn't had time to upgrade them yet. Since posting this I have upgraded, and I'm still getting the same issue.